# Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0xc0e8b0e1910)

Tags: swift, extension-methods, exc-bad-access

**Crashing**

its working fine in Xcode 9.4.1 swift 3.x

After using Xcode 10 swift 3.x app is crashing at objc_getAssociatedObject in the code snippet.

extension String {

```
struct AssociatedKey {
    static var associatedFormatterKey: UInt8 = 0
}

var associatedDateFormatter: DateFormatter {
    get {
        if let formatter = objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &AssociatedKey.associatedFormatterKey) as? DateFormatter {
            return formatter
        } else {
            let formatter = DateFormatter()
            formatter.locale = Locale.serverFormatterLocale
            objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &AssociatedKey.associatedFormatterKey, formatter, .OBJC_ASSOCIATION_ASSIGN)
            return formatter
        }
    }
}}
```

**After applying Zombie**

Error: [NSDateFormatter retain]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x6000067a4630

**Workaround:** updating objc_setAssociatedObject policy .OBJC_ASSOCIATION_ASSIGN to .OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN) working fine.

**I would like to know best workaround.**

Any help would be great.

Thanks

Comment: Your "workaround" looks to me just as a correct implementation. OBJC_ASSOCIATION_ASSIGN shouldn't be used here, because it makes a weak reference, which leads to premature release of the object.

Comment: @LiMar but why it was working fine in Xcode 9.4.1 and same is not working in Xcode 10?

Whats your opinion?

Comment: I don't know the differences in their compiler differences, but since it looks like a erroneous policy, the behaviour can be indeterministic, that means that it can even "look" like it's working. I hope more knowledgable people can explain more. And if you're really interested, run the thing under debugger and see what happens with retain/release under both Xcodes.

Comment: ok lets wait for others

Comment: There is no need to wait for others, @LiMar has already written the correct solution. It was pure "luck" that the _RETAIN_ version worked in the old Xcode 9; it never should have worked.

Comment: @Andreas Oetjen in Xcode 9 with Swift 3.x OBJC_ASSOCIATION_ASSIGN worked fine and causing crash in Xcode 10 with Swift 3.x.

instead OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN  works fine in Xcode 10 with Swift 3.x

But my concern is it good to go with OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN as it will increase retain count?